# Stencil CLI + SASS partial includes: file doesn't exist

Tags: sass, bigcommerce, node-sass, stenciljs

I am using stencil with `@bigcommerce` on the following software:

```
Windows 8
Node.js 7.10.0
Python 2.7.14
NPM 5.6.0
```

After running `stencil start` and then loading the site at the local URL it gives me an error like this:

```
[Browsersync] File event [change] : stencil/*.css
{ Error: layout\pdp.scss doesn't exist!
    at options.error (C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\@bigcommerce\node-sass\lib\index.js:277:32)
  formatted: 'Error: layout\\pdp.scss doesn\'t exist!\n        on line 207 of my-theme.scss\n>> @import \'layout/pdp\';\n   --------^\n',
  message: 'layout\\pdp.scss doesn\'t exist!',
  column: 9,
  line: 207,
  file: 'my-theme.scss',
  status: 1 }
```

The line in the SCSS file causing this is:

```
@import 'layout/pdp';
```

Now, on my co-worker's Mac this works. SASS looks for `./layout/_pdp.scss` and it loads just fine. But on my Windows PC this doesn't work. I've tried every variation of the import by including the underscore, including the extension, using `./` at the beginning, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work on Windows or with these versions of NPM, NodeJS, etc.?

Comment: What version of node-sass?

Comment: @nschonni I'm actually not sure. I can't figure out how to run commands against the version of sass in that directory.